power bi dax with loop function
I have a table for tool inspection like this. All the tools are inspected once per year. Format of date is date-month-year.
ToolNumber  InspectionDate  PurchaseDate
1           10-1-2024       10-3-2024
2           8-3-2024        12-11-2023
3           12-1-2024       1-7-2019

I want to add historical inspection dates in new rows with loop logic. The year of historical InspectionDate should begin in 2018. Condition is that, if the last InspectionDate (one year ago based on current InspectionDate) is older than PurchaseDate, then add no rows. Otherwise, add historical values in one new row.
In the end, the table should be changed to this:
ToolNumber  InspectionDate  PurchaseDate
1           10-1-2024       10-3-2024
2           8-3-2024        12-11-2023
3           12-1-2024       1-7-2019
3           12-1-2023       1-7-2019
3           12-1-2022       1-7-2019
3           12-1-2021       1-7-2019
3           12-1-2020       1-7-2019

How to write the dax code?
I tried to create a fictive table for historical values, but don't know how to use the loop function in power bi.

add your dax formulas which you've already tried... and also add your sample data and desired result table as table instead of photos...  Table Support

You need to use UNION to combine the rows that you have already with the rows that you will generate using GENSERIES from 2018 up to one year before the InspectionDate year.
Then, creates a cross-join between each row of ToolInspection and a series of years :
HistoricalInspections =
UNION (
    'ToolInspection',
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            GENERATE (
                'ToolInspection',
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    GENERATESERIES (2018, YEAR('ToolInspection'[InspectionDate]) - 1, 1),
                    "HistoricalYear", [Value]
                )
            ),
            DATE ( [HistoricalYear], MONTH ( 'ToolInspection'[InspectionDate] ), DAY ( 'ToolInspection'[InspectionDate] ) ) >= 'ToolInspection'[PurchaseDate]
        ),
        "ToolNumber", 'ToolInspection'[ToolNumber],
        "InspectionDate", DATE ( [HistoricalYear], MONTH ( 'ToolInspection'[InspectionDate] ), DAY ( 'ToolInspection'[InspectionDate] ) ),
        "PurchaseDate", 'ToolInspection'[PurchaseDate]
    )
)


